How can I make requests require authentication?
I'm trying to make an authentication system for my server for a game. I want certain routes to require you to be authenticated to interact with them. I would like to use Firebase authentication for this.
server.py:
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, jsonify
import time
import json
import jwt
import firebase
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

# All entries
@app.route("/entries")
def entries():
    return firebase.get_entries()

# Get specific entry
@app.route("/entries/<string:id>")
def entry(id):
    return firebase.get_entry(id)

# Get specific entry's property
@app.route("/entries/<string:id>/<string:property>")
def entry_property(id, property):
    return firebase.get_entry(id)[property]

# Create entry
@app.route("/create_entry/<string:id>")
def create_entry(id):
    try:
        name = request.args.get("name")
        description = request.args.get("description")

        entry = {
            "name": name,
            "description": description,
        }

        e = firebase.create_entry(id, entry)

        if e:
            return str(e)

        return f"Created entry with the id of {id}"
    except Exception as e:
        return e

# Remove "/" from end
@app.before_request
def trailing():
    from flask import redirect, request

    rp = request.path
    if rp != '/' and rp.endswith('/'):
        return "Don't use trailing backslashes. Example: /entries, not /entries/", 404


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)


frankly, I expected this information in first line, not in last. It can be the most important information in all this question - because Flask has already module flask_login and probably every visitor will think that you need only flask_login but I don't know if it can use firebase

flask login is not built-in but it is popular extension. And when I read your text require authentication then my first idea was that you are talking about flask login :)

hey guys, stop trying to edit this post, it is very annoying, thank you.
